# TTImageView not working

Tags: iphone, three20

I am new to IPhone and using following code to render the image from remote server using TTImageView from Three20 framework with the help of following code

```
TTImageView* imageView = [[[TTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 0, 0)] autorelease];

//Working OK
//imageView.urlPath = @"http://prosares.co.cc/Images/background.jpg";

//No Working
imageView.urlPath = @"http://prosares.co.cc/Images/backgroundTest.jpg"; 

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

As shown above if I am trying to load background.jpg it's getting loaded correctly but for some reason backgroundTest.jpg is not loading at all.

the only diffrance in these images are the size, is there any restriction on the image size that I can load in TTImageView ?

Can someone please help me to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the specific limit here but it's simply because your file is too large either in size (kb) or dimention (W x H). That's it.

EDIT: Found it while looking for something else :). Check out TTURLRequestQueue.m in Three20Network, around like 39.

```
static NSUInteger kDefaultMaxContentLength = 150000;
```